# Design of a boost converter with large variation in output current and low output ripple

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, boost, ripple

I'm working on the design of a 24V to 30V boost converter that needs to have an output ripple of less than 100 mV with an output current between 0 and 2 A.

The output is used to power a controller for a voice coil actuator. Unfortunately the controller only has a single power input and cannot be changed or modified. This means that the actuator drive current and analog sensor electronics are powered from the same supply. The boost converter needs to have a low output ripple to ensure the position sensors have low noise, and support a large variation in output current depending if the actuator is accelerating (2 A max.) or when it's just holding position (10-20 of mA).

I have preliminary selected the TPS55340 boost converter with integrated switch to use in my design. Using TI's WEBENCH and back-of-the-envelope calculations I selected a L = 12 uH inductor and using a switching frequency of 750 kHz. Pulse-skipping starts below 17 mA. It should be possible to avoid pulse-skipping by adding a minimal load.

The DCM-CCM boundary occurs at Iout_crit = 224 mA. I don't see an easy way to lower the DCM-CCM boundary, so I think I need to make it such that it operates well in both modes.

I am unsure on how to approach such a design making sure it will meet the max. ripple specification in all operating conditions. It would help me if someone could point me to a relevant application note or other source.

Thanks

EDITS:

- Change typo in part no.
- Added more design details

Comment: Your specs are incomplete , source datasheet specs, Controller & coil datasheet,  Load specs, f BW @ 2A, 100mV . Why can't low current sensors use filtered DC?  or even LDO many more missing specs.. try again

Comment: Boost converters need a load or they will either cause the output voltage to rise fairly uncontrollably or enter a pulse skipping mode. If you want to avoid pulse skipping, have a nominal load always present. If it's that big of a deal use a current monitor to determine if the "light load" can be disconnected.